# how to use UISegmentedControl to change datasource in tableview

Tags: iphone, sql, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableview

how to use UISegmentedControl to change datasource in tableview?
with sql tables 
or read data from arrays 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` (with events UIControlEventValueChanged) to set up a response action for the segmented control.
2. In the action, check the sender's `selectedSegmentIndex` property. Use this to determine which data source to use.
3. Change the table view's `dataSource` property.

Comment: @user: What textLabel? You did not mention textLabel in the question.